# specman event is counted although it wasn't fired

Tags: events, specman

My BFM should fire an event rd_trig_o.
As seen below rd_trig_o is an event port that is triggered after drive_packet was done:

```
unit collector_bfm_u like uvm_bfm {
    !p_smp : collector_smp_u;
    !p_drv : collector_driver_u;
    !pkt : collector_packet_s;
    p : collector_data;
    port_num : uint (bits:2);
    event clk_e is rise (p_smp.clk_in$) @sim;
    rd_addr_o : out buffer_port of addr_t is instance;
    rd_trig_o : out event_port is instance; 
    keep rd_addr_o.buffer_size() == 4;
    !rd_address_fifo : deque of (addr_t);

    run() is  {
        rd_address_fifo = new;
        start run_main_tcms();
    };

    run_main_tcms() @clk_e is {
        --wait true (p_smp.rst_in$ == 0); //  wait till reset is negated
        wait delay(10);
        message(LOW,"out of reset!!!");
        all of {
            {request_and_drive_packet()};
            {send_rd_address()};
        }
    };

    request_and_drive_packet() @clk_e is {
        while (TRUE) {
            pkt = p_drv.get_next_item();
            drive_packet( pkt );
            emit p_drv.item_done;
        };
    };

    drive_packet(req: collector_packet_s) @clk_e is {
        var signal_name : string;
        p_smp.i_we_b[port_num]$ = req.we_b;
        p_smp.i_addr_b[port_num]$ = req.addr_b;
        rd_address_fifo.push(req.addr_b);
        emit rd_trig_o$;
    };
```

My monitor should sample after event was fired.
sample_data()  TCM waits for an event rd_trig_i in order to sample data:

```
unit collector_monitor_u like uvm_monitor {
    !p_smp : collector_smp_u;
    event clk_e is fall (p_smp.clk_in$) @sim;
    port_num : uint (bits:2);
    rd_data_o : out buffer_port of data_t is instance;
    rd_trig_i : in event_port is instance;
    keep rd_data_o.buffer_size() == 4;
    
    run() is  {
        start run_main_tcms();
    };
    
    run_main_tcms() @clk_e is {
            sample_data();
    };
        
    sample_data() @rd_trig_i$ is {
        var rd_data: bit;
        var data_value: data_t;

        while (TRUE) do {
            wait cycle;
            rd_data = p_smp.i_we_b[port_num]$;
            if (rd_data == 0) {
                data_value = p_smp.o_q_b[port_num]$;
                rd_data_o.put(data_value);
                outf("read data = %d \n", data_value);
            }
        }
    };  
    
};
```

The monitor and bfm event ports are bind at the agent:

```
keep bind(bfm.rd_trig_o, mon.rd_trig_i);
```

But in the simulation the monitor sample without waiting for the event to be fired.
Why the monitor doesn't wait to bfm event?

Comment: I do not have an answer, the sample_data() should wait for the first rd_trg_i event before executing. One remark: never connect the BFM and the monitor, it violates the principle of separating the driving and monitoring aspects of an eVC.
Be also aware that the "wait cycle" in sample_data() TCM will wait for another rd_trg_i event.

Comment: the bfm and monitor are of the same agent. If I delete the event_port between them, then I would have to sample the data bus every cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a small example (kept only the stuff related to the event port), i can see that the monitor does get triggered correctly. are you sure it was triggered before the bfm emitted?

```
<'
struct collector_packet_s {};

unit collector_bfm_u  {
 
    !pkt : collector_packet_s;
    event clk_e is @sys.any; 
    rd_trig_o : out event_port is instance; 
  
    run() is also {
        start request_and_drive_packet();
    };

    request_and_drive_packet() @clk_e is {
        raise_objection(TEST_DONE);
        for i from 0 to 3 {
            wait [5] * cycle;
            gen pkt;
            drive_packet( pkt );
        };
        drop_objection(TEST_DONE);
    };

    drive_packet(req: collector_packet_s) @clk_e is {
        message(LOW, "drive_packet now emits");
        emit rd_trig_o$;
    };
}; 
unit collector_monitor_u  {
    event clk_e is @sys.any; 
    rd_trig_i : in event_port is instance;
    
    run() is  {
        start sample_data();
    };
    sample_data() @rd_trig_i$ is {
        message(LOW, "sample_data starts, ",
                "because the port was triggered");
        while (TRUE) do {
            wait cycle;
            message(LOW, "sample_data waited cycle, ",
                    " port triggered again");
        };
    };
};
unit env_u {
    bfm : collector_bfm_u is instance;
    mon: collector_monitor_u is instance;  
    keep bind(bfm.rd_trig_o, mon.rd_trig_i);  
};
extend sys {
   env : env_u is instance;
};
```

Comment: I moved "wait cycle;" to the end of the while loop, and it worked for me.